# Android resource folder for exact screen size

Tags: android, resources, screen-size

Starting from Android 3.2 I have this strange problem.

It's very easy to reproduce:

1. Create an empty project;
2. Add values-480x320/ resource directory to it;
3. Change some string in this new folder, e.g. @string/hello, to be different from default one inside the values/ directory.

Now, on 3.1 and lower Android devices and emulators, everything is as you'd expect it to be. But on 3.2 and higher (including 4.x Galaxy Nexus and emulators), values-480x320/ is used instead of values/ folder!!

It's worth to mention that I don't see that compatibility "Stretch/Zoom to fill screen" icon. I tried changing supports-screens and uses-sdk tags in AndroidManifest.xml but they won't fix this problem.

So my question is: why is this happening and what can you advice to fix it?

PS, I really don't see any reason why such a minor change in Android version from 3.1 to 3.2 has to break older apps!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look here, maybe it will help: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

Comment: No one has ever used "*-480x320/" resources in Android????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you're interested: the advice is basically not to use fixed resolution-based resource folders like values-480x320.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in 3.2 was some changed [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) algorithm. Try to create different values folders with qualifiers mentiond [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt support guys!
If I remove older style (e.g. values-480x320) folders and replace them with new-style (e.g. values-sw320dp) folders, the problem will be fixed on new 3.2+ platforms. But at the same time, layout will break on 3.1 and lower Androids because they simply don't "understand" new 3.2-style-suffixes...

Comment: And what happens if you have both folders in res - with new and old suffixes?

Comment: Generally, new-style folders are completely ignored, and replaced by 480x320 folder if there is one. But I was trying various combinations of old and new styles and found something useful - for WVGA800/240dpi emulator you can declare values-sw300dp, and this folder will make it so that resources from values-480x320 will be "ignored" - if you don't specify @string/hello in values-sw300dp, the @string/hello from default values/ directory is going to be used. This fix is really messy, so I'm searching for something better.